# Power BI refresh: organizational account refresh

Tags: powerbi

I have a Power BI report which pulls data from a SharePoint 2013 (on premise) list. The SharePoint belongs to a different organization so the report uses organizational account to read the list via oData source.

The report works fine locally. The problem is when we publish the report to Power BI service, and edit the credential setting for report refresh, we cannot find Organizational Account setting.

Does anyone have this problem/scenario before? and how can we refresh the report in this case? thanks in advance.

Comment: Found a solution?

Comment: Do you have two separate tenants ?